# How to add a fragment in my activity dynamically?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am using Android Studio which implements all the functions of a fragment class. I am getting following runtime exception:

```
must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener
```

Here is my code and I have implemented the `OnFragmentInteractionListener` in my main activity.

**MAIN ACTIVITY:**

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements BlankFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if (findViewById(R.id.fragment_container) != null) {
            BlankFragment fragment = new BlankFragment();
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
            ft.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment).commit();
        }
    @Override            
    public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri) {}

}
```

**BLANK FRAGMENT:**

```
public class BlankFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {
    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;
    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }

    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }
}
```

The remaining methods of fragment class and main activity are also implemented by default. I have also changed `LinearLayout` with `FrameLayout` in the main_activity.xml`file and also assigned`android:id` to it which is referenced fine. What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Have you initialised the `mListener` the object of the interface with the activity??

Comment: Are you using android.support.v4.app.Fragment as base class in BlankFragment or android.app.Fragment?

Comment: Your code is not clear. Please repaste the two class (activity and fragment)

Comment: No i have not initialized the mlistener object in the main activity.

Comment: I am using android.support.v4.aoo.Fragment as base class in Blank Fragment.

Comment: Code indentation + inline code formatting + minor changes to text

Comment: I've put up an answer that may be of use - if not, it would be helpful to see more of your `BlankFragment` class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To interact with your `BlankFragment` object, I would use the following method recommended in the [Android Support Docs](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html) - I believe this is what you are trying to achieve, and it will be suitable as your `BlankFragment` object is hosted by `MainActivity`:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements BlankFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener    {

private BlankFragment fragment = null;
private android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager manager = null;
private android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft;

public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri){
        Log.i("Tag", "onFragmentInteraction called");
    }

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (manager == null) manager = getSupportFragmentManager();            

    if(manager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container) == null) {

        //If a fragment is not already loaded into your container, then add one...

        fragment = new BlankFragment();
        ft= manager.beginTransaction();
        ft.add(R.id.fragment_container,fragment).commit();
    }
}
```

In order to communicate with your fragment, you would do the following:

```
if(fragment == null) {
    fragment = (BlankFragment) manager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
}
```

You can then call any methods associated with `fragment`

If it's the other way round (communication from fragment to activity), then you would need to do the following in `BlankFragment` to form a link with the parent `Activity`:

```
//Class variable...
OnFragmentInteractionListener mCallback;

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try {
        mCallback = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) activity;
            } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }
```

You may have forgotten about this last step, which could explain your error. You would then use:

```
mCallback.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
```

To communicate with `MainActivity`

Comment: i have just started java a week ago. and i certainly dont understand a lot of code in the blank activity. I just want to show a textbox which is in fragment layout. this code is implemented by default by android studio.    

public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }
  
 there is no button attached to the fragment.xml i dont understand this auto generated piece.

Comment: @user3859323 Was it a sample project created by Android Studio? If so, how did you create it? I'll duplicate it my end and take a look.

Comment: No it is not a sample project. when i click at my app and add a fragment i selected blankFragment and it generated its java and xml. Create a project and add a blank fragment to your activity that is all i tried to do.

Comment: it worked on its own. i added a view then removed it and it worked :D

Comment: @user3859323 Great! For what it's worth, I followed the steps you took and created a working example that demonstrates Fragment/Activity communication. You can download, edit and run it etc. for yourself if you like. It may help with your studies, as this can be a complex topic. The link to get it is on my GitHub page: https://github.com/PPartisan/FragmentInterfaceExample Just download the zip file and open it in Android Studio

Comment: Thanks i sure will :)

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me, I have just shared it here you never know it will help out some one else.

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment).commit();
```

Just one line of code.