# How to add fragment in activity

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments

I want to add fragment in my activity but i don't know how can i do this i check multiple answers in stack overflow but i don't get it kindly help me please.

This is my Activity layout (activity_home.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.foodshahi.www.foodshahi.Home">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:background="#000000">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Your Location: "
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/user_location_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView"
            android:text="Test"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/change_location"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:onClick="changeLocation"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
            android:text="@string/change_location"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:src="@drawable/logo"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
        <LinearLayout android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_height="0px"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout2" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/search"
            android:hint="Search by Food and Chef"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <fragment
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/home_fragment">
</fragment>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is my Activity class (Home.java):

```
 public class Home extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView menuTextView;
    ExpandableRelativeLayout expandableLayout1;
    ImageView lunchImageView;
    String cityName;
    TextView cityNameTextView;
    LunchResultFragment lunchResultFragment;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        MenuFragment menuFragment = new MenuFragment();
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.home_fragment,menuFragment)
                .commit();
        }

    }
```

This is my Fragment layout (menu_fragment.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:id="@+id/menu_text_view"
                android:text="@string/home_menu"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                />

            <com.github.aakira.expandablelayout.ExpandableRelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/expandableMenuLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_below="@+id/menu_text_view"
                android:background="#FFFF"
                android:padding="16dp"
                app:ael_duration="400"
                app:ael_expanded="false"
                app:ael_interpolator="accelerate"
                app:ael_orientation="vertical">

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/button"
                    android:text="Home"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:id="@+id/menu_home_button"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/button"
                    android:layout_below="@id/menu_home_button"
                    android:text="Order Food"
                    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                    android:id="@+id/menu_order_food"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>
                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/button"
                    android:layout_below="@id/menu_order_food"
                    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                    android:text="Special Deal"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:id="@+id/menu_special_deal"/>


                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/button"
                    android:layout_below="@id/menu_special_deal"
                    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                    android:text="Chef Special"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:id="@+id/menu_chef_special"/>

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/button"
                    android:layout_below="@id/menu_chef_special"
                    android:text="Restaurant"
                    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                    android:id="@+id/menu_restaurant"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>
                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/button"
                    android:layout_below="@id/menu_restaurant"
                    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                    android:text="Home Made"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:id="@+id/menu_home_made"/>
                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/button"
                    android:layout_below="@id/menu_home_made"
                    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                    android:text="Bakery"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:id="@+id/menu_bakery"/>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/button"
                    android:layout_below="@id/menu_bakery"
                    android:id="@+id/menu_cart"
                    android:layout_marginTop="2dp">
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/cart"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/cart_text_view"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        />
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/cart_text_view"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Cart"
                        android:textAllCaps="true"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:textSize="18sp"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="0"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/cart_text_view"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>
                </RelativeLayout>


            </com.github.aakira.expandablelayout.ExpandableRelativeLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_height="220dp"
        android:id="@+id/banner_relative_layout"
        android:background="@drawable/banner">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/breakfast"
            android:layout_width="600dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
            android:src="@drawable/breakfast" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/breakfast"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:src="@drawable/lunch"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:id="@+id/lunch" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:id="@+id/dinner"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/lunch"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/lunch"
            android:layout_below="@+id/lunch"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:src="@drawable/dinner" />

    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/home_restaurant"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:textSize="18sp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is my Fragment java class (MenuFragment.java):

```
public class MenuFragment extends Fragment {
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_fragment,container,false);
    return rootView;
}
}
```

When i run app then it crashes and show me this error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.foodshahi.www.foodshahi, PID: 5330
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.foodshahi.www.foodshahi/com.foodshahi.www.foodshahi.Home}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class fragment
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2572)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2654)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1488)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5728)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
                   Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class fragment
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
                      at com.foodshahi.www.foodshahi.Home.onCreate(Home.java:32)
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6331)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1113)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2519)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2654) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1488) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5728) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679) 
                   Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class fragment
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:782)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
                      at com.foodshahi.www.foodshahi.Home.onCreate(Home.java:32) 
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6331) 
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1113) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2519) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2654) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1488) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5728) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679) 
                   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                      at java.lang.VMClassLoader.findLoadedClass(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.ClassLoader.findLoadedClass(ClassLoader.java:362)
                      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:499)
                      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
                      at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.isSupportFragmentClass(Fragment.java:499)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:3637)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:111)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:338)
                      at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityApi14.onCreateView(BaseFragmentActivityApi14.java:39)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:67)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:754)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
                      at com.foodshahi.www.foodshahi.Home.onCreate(Home.java:32) 
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6331) 
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1113) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2519) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2654) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1488) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5728) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a fragment in my activity dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31425672/how-to-add-a-fragment-in-my-activity-dynamically)

Comment: Please learn basic Android elements first, its types and how to use it. You are trying to make an app without knowledge of what fragments are and how it can be used on Activity.

Answer (score 1):

First thing, You should use

```
  <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1">

</FrameLayout>
```

Also check that the Fragment you are extending in your class is **android.app.Fragment** and **getFragmentManager** is that of android.app.Fragment. People usually conflicts by extending **android.support.v4.Fragment**

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
<fragment
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/home_fragment">
```

to

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp" //any particular size
    android:id="@+id/home_fragment"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add the fragment class details in the xml if you use `<fragment />` using `android:name="com.example.android.fragments.MyFragment"`.
No need of any code in the activity in this case.

As this information is not available in the xml, inflator throws `InflateException` and your app crashes.

**Refer the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating.html).**

If you want to do it programatically, add any `ViewGroup` preferably a `FrameLayout` and add the `Fragment` via `FragmentManager`. Also it's possible to add to the default `android.R.id.content` which is the base `ViewGroup` in which all your views in the layout are added.

Answer (score 0):

> To add a `fragment` into a `Activity` or `FramentActivity` it requires
>   a Container. That container should be a "`Framelayout`", which can be
>   included in xml or else you can use the default container for that
>   like "`android.R.id.content`" to remove or replace a `fragment` in
>   `Activity`.

For Example:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Comment: There is a TextView in my fragment and i want  to apply click listener on it how can i do this?

Comment: Do you want to set click listener for `TextView` in main activity? Or you want to add it into fragment?

Comment: TextView is in fragment and i want to apply click listener on it

Comment: Same as like `Activity` you want to handle it inside a `fragment` class.

Comment: @KamranAli Refer this example http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidFragments/article.html